# Hibernate - mapping two parent table to one child table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I am facing a small problem in creating hibernate mapping files for below sort:

```
Table A
|-- Table B
|    |
|-- Table C
```

1. **Table B** has a column from **Table A** as foreign key
2. **Table C** has a column from **Table A** and a column from **Table B**, both as foreign key

I have created .hbm files that take care of inserting the Foreign Key (Table A) in **Table B** and insertion of Foreign Key (Table B) in **Table C**, but I am unable to insert the Foreign Key (Table A) in **Table C**.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Saurabh